# Malloc/free algorithm in Suse

Tags: linux, malloc, suse

Which implementation of malloc/free is used in a specific Linux distribution (in my case Suse 9 and Suse 10) ?

Has it change between both versions ?

Is it the same algorithm for 32 bits and 64 bits versions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`malloc` and `free` are implemented in the C library rather than the operating system itself. If you find out what C library you have, you can know this. I don't know Suse but most linuxes will be using glibc (the GNU version of the C standard library).